# nestjs-i18n translation not working as expected

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I tried nestjs-i18n, configured without any compiling error, but when I try `i18n.t(en.firstName)`. It giving exact `en.firstName` instead of translated content from `en.json` with key `firstName`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    I18nModule.forRoot({
      fallbackLanguage: 'en',
      loaderOptions: {
        path:  path.join(__dirname,'/i18n/'),
        watch: true,
      },
      resolvers: [
        { use: QueryResolver, options: ['lang'] },
        AcceptLanguageResolver,
      ],
    }),
```

my en.json file this

```
{
    "login" : {
        "FIRST": "ENGLISH"
    }
}
```

when i try to get translated content with  `i18n.t(`login.FIRST`)` instead of en.json content, i am getting plain text login.FIRST